# Pass inputField values as queryString to another page in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, prettyfaces

I am attempting to allow a user to enter a string into an inputText component and then by pressing enter or clicking a button/link pass the entered string onto another page as a parameter called 'queryString'.

I am using Prime faces and Pretty faces.

*I have tried several different things. Working from the JSF page code itself:*

```
<p:panel 
    id="quickSearch" 
    header="Quick Search" 
    toggleable="true" 
    closable="false" 
    toggleSpeed="500" 
    closeSpeed="500">

    <h:form>    

        <p:inputText 
            id="queryStringInput"
            name="queryStringInput"
            value="#{dBean.queryString}" />

        <p:commandLink
            id="submitQuery"
            ajax="false"
            value="Search"
            type="submit"
            action="pretty:content">

            <f:param 
            id="queryString"
            name="queryString" 
            value="#{dBean.queryString}" />

        </p:commandLink>    

    </h:form>       

</p:panel>
```

**another way:**

```
<p:panel 
    id="quickSearch" 
    header="Quick Search" 
    toggleable="true" 
    closable="false" 
    toggleSpeed="500" 
    closeSpeed="500">

    <h:form>    

        <p:inputText 
            id="queryStringInput"
            name="queryStringInput"
            value="#{dBean.queryString}" />

    <h:link 
        id="link"
        outcome="pretty:content" 
        value="Search" >

        <f:param 
            id="queryString"
            name="queryString" 
            value="#{dBean.queryString}" />

    </h:link>   

    </h:form>       

</p:panel>
```

I have also tried making the bean do the forwarding work:

**Page code :**

```
<p:panel 
    id="quickSearch" 
    header="Quick Search" 
    toggleable="true" 
    closable="false" 
    toggleSpeed="500" 
    closeSpeed="500">

    <h:form>    

        <p:inputText 
            id="queryStringInput"
            name="queryStringInput"
            value="#{dBean.queryString}" />

        <p:commandButton 
            id="submitQuery"
            ajax="false"
            value="Search"
            actionListener="#{dBean.runSearch}" />

    </h:form>       

</p:panel>
```

**Bean :**

```
public void runSearch() {
    logger.debug("the query string is: " +getQueryString());

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler handler = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

    String url = "/content?queryString=" + getQueryString();
    handler.handleNavigation(context, null, url);

}
```

I can't seem to get it to work the way I want. Here is the snippet from pretty config:

```
<url-mapping id="content">
    <pattern value="/content"/>
    <query-param name="queryString">#{searchCriteria.queryString}</query-param>
    <view-id value="/pages/content.jsf"/>
</url-mapping>
```

I don't believe it matters which way it is accomplished (from page code or bean) as long as it works.

Thanks for any and all help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing a searchCriteria bean in your pretty-config. Can you use that for your p:inputText value (or vice versa)? Pretty faces should pick up the query parameter then.

```
<p:inputText 
    id="queryStringInput"
    name="queryStringInput"
    value="#{searchCriteria.queryString}" />

<p:commandLink
    id="submitQuery"
    value="Search"
    type="submit"
    action="pretty:content">
</p:commandLink>
```